# FillConsoleOutputCharacter/WriteConsoleOutput and special characters

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, console

I'm messing with some of the native windows console functions, and am impressed by their speed,if not their ease of use.

Anyway, I have long known that the following code will produce some interesting characters

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    cout << char(i) << endl;
}
```

However, I cannot get FillConsoleOutputCharacter  or WriteConsoleOutput to produce all of those characters (many simply appear as question marks).

Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
COORD spot = {0,0};
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD Written;

for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hOut, 7, 1, spot, &Written);
    FillConsoleOutputCharacterW(hOut, char(i), 1, spot, &Written);

    spot.Y++;
}
```

Does anyone know of a relatively convenient way to write those characters with the native functions?

By the way, I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FillConsoleOutputCharacterA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should write the same set of characters that the cout function does.  These characters are determined by the console's current code page.

With FillConsoleOutputCharacterW, you can still generate all the same characters (as well as any additional characters that may be included in the console font) but you need to use the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_plane) (16-bit) codes for these characters, rather than the 8-bit codes used with cout.

Note that Windows internally uses an out-of-date version of Unicode, with characters limited to 16 bits (0-65536) rather than Unicode proper which uses 0-1,112,063 (although most of these codes remain unassigned).  I believe the console's Unicode character set corresponds to plane 0 of Unicode, the basic multilingual plane.

The question marks appear when you write a control character or a character that isn't included in the current font.

Comment: Thanks a lot! FillConsoleOutputCharacterA and WriteConsoleOutputA work perfectly. Would it do me any good to use unicode at all in a windows console? My (admittedly limited) understanding is that output in a console is limited to 256 characters (as defined by a code page, which I am also fuzzy on). Regardless, thanks a lot for this detailed, prompt, and helpful reply!

Comment: Using Unicode bypasses the code page, which means you can use as many different characters as you like (no 256-character limit) although you're still limited to the characters included in the console's font.  You can select a different font if the default one doesn't include the character(s) you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try using FillConsoleOutputCharacterA instead of FillConsoleOutputCharacterW which is using the unicode character which can take a little bit of knowledge to get correctly.

*edit* I tried using FillConsoleOutputCharacterA and it gives equivalent output to your first case.